# Efficient coding in Netlogo, many procedures or few?

Tags: performance, netlogo, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

In terms of increasing the performance on a model in NetLogo is it better to code with as many procedures as possible or as few for example...

(apologies for the very crude example, new to coding)

I ask this because when coding quite complex procedures with many commands it "looks" alot neater coding with many procedures.

MANY PROCEDURES

```
to move
    forward
    turn
end

to forward
    fd 1
end

to turn
    rt random 10
    lt random 10
end
```

OR

LESS PROCEDURES

```
to move
    fd 1
    rt random 10
    lt random 10
end
```

Cheers,

Harri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of organization has virtually no impact on performance whatsoever. Performance problems are almost always due to algorithmic problems (for instance, asking all turtles to ask all patches, when you really only needed to just ask all patches) rather than organization of code.

I highly recommend always organizing your code to be as readable as possible. This makes it much easier to spot algorithmic problems, helping you identify the real reasons for poor performance.

Finally, you should check out the [profiler extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html). It comes with NetLogo. It will breakdown exactly how much time each procedure is taking and how much each procedure is being called. This will help you identify the problematic points in your code and determine for a certainty if a particular change to code improves performance. If you organize your code into many procedures, the profiler will be able to give you more fine grained results. Note, however, you can easily go overboard with having many procedures and hurt readability.

For organization of code, readability should always be the number one priority. Sometimes, you may have to implement an algorithm that is more complicated either for functionality or performance reasons, and thus may be harder to read. Some algorithms are simply harder to reason about and thus harder to read by nature. You should still do what you can in the organization of your implementation of the algorithm to maximize readability.